# Convert google map v2 custom overlay to v3 custom overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have been doing so much research and yet to find the exact answer to help me.  I need to convert my map at http://www.uaf.edu/campusmap/ from V2 to V3 so I can try to combine it with my fusion tables. It uses tiles made by Map Tiler. Is there anyone who can help me out?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to port the whole map to V3 and use [Custom Map Types](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#CustomMapTypes).

BTW, you're loading the API twice, once from http://www.uaf.edu/files/campusmap/ and then again from http://www.uaf.edu/files/campusmap/campusmap-122311.html -- which is loaded in an iframe. Probably better to remove one of them, I think you can get rid of the first one.

Comment: Thank you Miguev, I have totally torn it apart and built it back up again.  I have a small issue now and I have the feeling it is something really dumb.  It is at http://www.justawebbie.freehostingcloud.com/test-map4.html would you mind taking a look at it and let me know the silly mistake I made. thank you again for  your help.

Comment: I just looked and didn't find anything wrong, what's the undesired symptom?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two main things you'll need to worry about when converting to v3:

`GTileOverlay` doesn't exist in v3. You can use Custom Map Types, as per the pp.
To do this, you'll want to make an `ImageMapType` [(see the docs)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html). You'll then need to add this to the `Map.overlayMapTypes` `MVCArray` (which will display it above the base map - [Map reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map)).

There's nothing like `GDownloadUrl` and `GXml` for downloading and parsing an XML document in v3. You'll need to use a generic library like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to help downloading your marker locations.

Comment: Thank you Dave. I was able to to convert it to V3 but I think I have done something very silly with it. I can not seem to get the minzoom and center set.  I know it is probably something so small and dumb. Can you take a look at it for me and tell me what mistake I made. It is at http://www.justawebbie.freehostingcloud.com/test-map4.html Thank you for your help again.

Comment: That looks good to me. What is your exact problem? Might be worth opening a new SO question if it's still bothering you.